# How can I change the style of unnumbered and numbered chapters differently?

Tags: latex

I'm writing a document using the scrbook class and compiling with xelatex. I'm trying to format the chapters so that the title is in one page and then the content starts in the next page. I managed to do it but by doing so, the unnumbered chapters act the same and the contents' title is in one page and the list on the next one. How can I keep this chapters' format without changing the unnumbered ones?

A summary of the code I used is:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{calc}


% Estilo de página de capítulo:
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
afterskip=\glueexpr 0pt plus 1fil ,
beforeskip=\glueexpr 0pt plus 1fil + \baselineskip,
innerskip=20pt
]{chapter}
\renewcommand{\chapterheadendvskip}{\clearpage}

\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
    {\chapapp~\thechapter\autodot}}


\let\originalchapterlinesformat\chapterlinesformat
\renewcommand*\chapterlinesformat[3]{%
    \Ifstr{#1}{chapter}
    {%
        \IfArgIsEmpty{#2}
        {\originalchapterlinesformat{#1}{#2}{#3}}
        {#2:\par%
            {{#3}\par\bigskip%
                \hrule%
            }%
        }%
    }
    {\originalchapterlinesformat{#1}{#2}{#3}}%
}


\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Just to clarify, I'm not trying to change the content of the list of contents but the format of the unnumbered chapter's titles (and the toc is an unnumbered chapter so I'm having this problem there).

I hope I explained myself (this is the first time I ask something).

Thanks in advance